# Шифровать изображение в изображение. Как лучше всего?

Tags: изображения, шифрование

Итак, хочется реализовать следующую идею: открываем изображение, считываем попиксельно, шифруем данные RGB пикселей неким текстовым ключом, составляем изображение попиксельно с измененными данными RGB.

Финальное изображение (естественно бессмысленное с виду) в итоге может подвергаться небольшим изменением размера или подвергаться появлению артефактов сжатия JPEG в разумных пределах. Из чего я делаю вывод, что никакие блочные алгоритмы шифрования данных в этом случае не подойдут, а шифрование независимо каждого пикселя будет слишком слабым.

Есть идеи?

---

**Update.** Если не касаться проблемы изменения размеров, то получается красиво:

[Исходное](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11039138/crypt-jpeg.jpg) → [зашифрованное](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11039138/crypted.png) → [дешифрованное](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11039138/decrypted.jpg)

Тут проблема в том, что шифрованное изображение подвергается сильным искажениям при изменении размеров, JPEG сжатии и прочим, так как по сути такого рода графическое изображение нужно хранить именно в битмапе (что делает этот подход не приемлимым в современных реалиях). Остаётся попробовать увеличивать шифрованное изображение раза в два три, чтобы каждый отдельный пиксель был площадью в 2 или 3 пикселя. А перед дефишровкой искать алгоритм наиболее удачного возвращения к исходным размерам.

Comment: @trashmajor, а чего вообще Вы хотите добиться?

Зашифровать файл (в одном из общеизвестных форматов) с изображением так, чтобы изображение стало *другим*, но осталось изображением в том же формате?

А после возможного редактирования (зашифрованного изображения) можно было восстановить исходное?

Comment: Есть некое изображение, которое вы публикуете в общем доступе. Те кто имеют ключ, смогут посмотреть исходное изображение.

Comment: Упрощенный немного вариант моей задачи : ) С интересом наблюдаю.

Comment: Кодирование цвета пикселей Hénon sequence http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map ничего не дало, как только сохраняем изображение в формате jpeg, малейшие колебания цвета пикселя сильно меняют изображение после дешифровки. Без потерь шифруется только bitmap без изменений. Изменение же размеров изображения дешифровки не подлежит.

Comment: Нашел [материал по теме](http://testlab.sit.fraunhofer.de/downloads/Publications/Poller_SPIE2012_Robust_Image_Obfuscation_for_Privacy_Protection.pdf) (pdf на англ)

Comment: Прекрасно что материал мотирован теми же побуждениями. Но готового решения в нём нет, и это вообщем-то удручает.

Comment: погуглите алгоритм коха-жао

Comment: стенография. не то.

Answer (score 2):

В точности по вашему случаю: можно обойтись перемешиванием пикселей, или лучше усреднённых цветов областей размера `width/N x height/N`. Кодовое слово определяет алгоритм "обхода" поля картинки, так, чтобы за конечное число шагов покрыть все изображение, побывав в любом месте хотя бы раз (возможно несколько). И банально попарно менять области местами каждые два шага. Если слово будет определять алгоритм обхода "векторно" - без привязки к точным пикселям, то изменения размера картинки не должны сильно ухудшить результат расшифровки.

Другие мысли:
Надо суметь в изображении сохранять несколько "слоёв" данных: от крупных признаков, до мелких деталей. Тогда при изменении размера или ацкой компресии пропадут, скажем, совсем мелкие детали, но более крупные признаки и суть изображения останутся.

Погуглите про [частотное разложение изображений](http://zhur74.livejournal.com/998.html). Например, с двумя частотами, исходное раскладывается на два изображения такого же размера:

1. исходная картинка сильно блюрится (уходят мелкие детали) - это низкочастотный канал.
2. разница исходной и блюренной - серенькое изображение — содержит только мелкие детали.

Сложив определенным образом эти два изображения, получается снова исходное, пиксель-в-пиксель. В ретуши так, например, можно легко избавиться от веснушек на коже, выделив их в отдельный частотный канал и замазав там в сплошной серый.

Так вот, интуиция подсказывает, что:

- нужно раскладывать изображение по
     частотам и шифровать их отдельно ==
     устойчивость к компрессии/уменьшению;
- шифрованное изображение должно
     содержать наложение нескольких слоев
     информации одновременно;
- размер признаков кореллирует с радиусом размытия данного слоя.

Для [Processing](http://processing.org/)'а был такой пример эффекта "поинтилизма": в исходной картинке выбираются случайные квадратные области, блюрятся - берется усреднённый цвет, и в новой картинке рисуется полупрозрачный круг этого цвета, вписанный в тот квадрат.
И они рисуются снова и снова, разных размеров. По мере роста числа этих вроде бы случайных кругов случайных цветов, начинает вырисовываться исходная картинка.

Answer (score 0):

А если сохранить данные о цвете каждого пиксела в изображении, сделать его ч/б и подвергнуть его шифрованию. Данные о цвете сохранить в заголовке или в конце файла с изображением

Посомотрите на этот пример, если владеете С++
[link text](https://github.com/markwatson/Image-Encrypt)

Comment: А что мне даёт отделение цвета?

Comment: При сжатии в JPG меньше потерь, хотя могу и ошибаться

Answer (score -1):

изображение запихать в `base64`, а `base64` зашифровать в `TrueCrypt` или тому подобное (`anubis` там например).

Или сразу напрямую шифровать, если такое возможно.

Ну и в конце посмотреть в интернете, как умельцы к картинкам добавляли архивы. 
При всём этом нужно помнить, что большинство пикчехранилищ пересохраняют картинки.

Comment: Заметьте, вопрос как раз таки содержит указание на то, что картинка должна быть расшифрована даже после изменения размеров или с появлением артефактов сжатия.

Comment: @trashmajor заметил. что-нибудь придумаю.

Comment: Я решил кодировать цвет пикселей. Генерирую псевдослучайные числа такой функцией k = 1-a*(возвести в степень(k, 2))+b*k , где k = псевдослучайное число, а параметры а и b заданы заранее. Не могу найти способа получить из этой функции числа в диапазоне 0 - 255 так, чтобы при XOR'е цветов пикселей создавался эффект действительно случайных значений.